# npm install has failed i got "ECONNRESET" error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Furkan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-30T19_43_10_482Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install has failed.

In case the error is caused by cache memory I cleared the cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

but I couldn't fix it.